Does the implication "if $f(x_1) < f(x_2) \implies x_1 < x_2$ then f is strictly increasing" stand?
More formally I want a proof of:
$$\forall x_1 x_2,(f(x_1) < f(x_2) \implies x_1 < x_2) \implies (x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) < f(x_2))$$
Apart from the rigorous proof I would appreciate an intuitive explanation as to why (or why not) this proposition stands.

I assumed the given implication and that $x_1 < x_2$. For the sake of contradiction I also assumed $f(x_1) \ge f(x_2)$. This splits into two cases one being greater than and the other being equal. I cannot derive a contradiction from the $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ case.

This is not true.   Consider the function $f(x)$ which is $0$ if $x≤0$ and $x$ if $x>0$.  Then it is certainly true that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)\implies x_1<x_2$, but $f$ is not strictly increasing.
For an even simpler example, if $f(x)$ is identically $0$ then the implication holds vacuously, yet constant functions are not strictly increasing.
It is true that the given implication tells us that $f$ is weakly increasing.  That is, it implies that $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)≤f(x_2)$.  Indeed, knowing that $f$ was not weakly increasing would mean that there was a pair of real numbers with $x_1<x_2$ and $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ and that pair would contradict the assumed implication.
